# Flutter web supabse Oauth redirection issue

Tags: flutter, oauth, supabase, supabase-flutter

```
ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      
                      if(defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android){
                        signInWithGoogle();
                      }

                      if(kIsWeb){
                        final data = await  supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth(Provider.google);
                        
                      }


                    },
                    child: const Text("Google Sign In"),
                  ),
```

I am able to sign in mobile and while in web i am successfully getting the auth token and i am redirect to
http://localhost:44769/#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1.....

and i am getting this error show in the screen
GoException: no routes for location: access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIm

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL strategy](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies) to make it work with Flutter web.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';

void main() async {
  usePathUrlStrategy();

  await Supabase.initialize(...);

  runApp(ExampleApp());
}
```

Comment: I hope this works